# Splitting whole text to words using one regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am looking for solution of problem. I need to create a kind of method which creates list of words and **just words**, for any given text, **including non-English letters and special characters**. I searched a lot and i was reading documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but any of this doesn't work perfectly for me. One of the best is this one:

```
String line = "    W metal, w liczbę, w trupie ciało, -"
String[] words = line.split("\\P{javaLetter}+");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (!words[i].equals("")) {  // I don't want to check everytime
            anotherList.add(word[i].toLowerCase())
        }
    }
}
```

but the result is:

```
["", "W", "metal", "w", "liczbę", "w", "trupie", "ciało"]
```

This spaces at the beginning of String breaks down my regex.
Which is the correct regex for making words in any language using latin alphabet (don't care about apostrophes in English words)?

Comment: have you tried line.Split(" ")? it makes sense to split on spaces to get the words in a sentence. Regex is great, but also very finicky.

Comment: Are you printing `words` or `anotherList`?

Comment: @tobias_k obviously words because anotherList wouldn't have the empty string that exists in the first index of his result .

Comment: @RichardBarker What's why I was asking, but it's not really clear from the question. So I guess the actual question is: What regex to use so that `words` is the same as `anotherList` right away?

Comment: do you really need to split? could you use a pattern and iterate over the matches?

Comment: The result is printed words array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the opposite approach - matching:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
String line = "    W metal, w liczbę, w trupie ciało, -";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+").matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    words.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(words); // => [W, metal, w, liczbę, w, trupie, ciało]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/taXkR1). The `\\p{L}+` will match 1+ any Unicode letters.

There is a way to use splitting approach, but we need to pre-process the input string first:

```
String line = "    W metal, w liczbę, w trupie ciało, -";
String[] words = line.replaceFirst("^\\P{L}+", "").split("\\P{L}+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/uuaAIY)

The `.replaceFirst("^\\P{L}+", "")` will remove all non-letter symbols from the beginning of the string, thus, leaving no empty elements in the split array.

Comment: I guess this _is_ the better approach. It's a shame Java does not have a simpler method for getting all the matches, though.

Comment: The best solution. Thank you. I don't have to use split, but I thought it is the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the result of `words` to be the same as `anotherList` but without post-processing the results in a loop. How about some preprocessing then?

```
String line = "    W  metal,  w  liczbę,   w  trupie ciało, -";
String[] words = line.trim().toLowerCase().split("\\P{javaLetter}+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Result: `[w, metal, w, liczbę, w, trupie, ciało]`

Comment: And if there is a non-letter/non-whitespace at the beginning? :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, I guess in this case there will still be some `''` in the result... :-/

Answer (score 0):

First the single upper quote in its variations I have added. Then all letters, and zero-width accents which combine with the letters.

```
String[] rawWords = line.trim().split("(?U)[^\\p{L}\\p{M}'\u0060\u00b4\u2017]");
```

Look in the javadoc of Pattern for the regex.

This will not prevent a preceding empty word, if the line does not start with a word. That could be replaced too, but a check would suffice.

Another problem is that every single quote is thought to be a part of a word.
This can be done by removing all leading and trailing sequences of quotes of words.

I would not try to make one single regex though that is certainly possible for the quote problem.

One simplification is the usage of Unicode text normalization. `"ŝ"` could be one char `\u0150` or two chars `c` plus a zero-width `^`. This can be done with the class `java.text.Normalizer`. Then `\\p{M}` could no longer be needed if you use the combined form.
Also all those single-quotes could be replaced by say the apostrophe `'`.

*(For natural language processing JNLP might be of interest.)*